# Adding some text in FarPoint while Export To Excel

Tags: c#, farpoint-spread, farpoint

I am having FarPoint Web Spread and a Panel with a text box [T1] in my webpage. I am using SaveExcel method of FpSpread to write the contents into Excel.

Is there any way by which i can write the contents of text box [T1] into the excel.

Below is the code I am using for export to excel -

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=Export.xls;");
        Response.Charset = "";
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
          FpSpread1.ActiveSheetView.Protect = false;
          FpSpread1.SaveExcel(ms, FarPoint.Excel.ExcelSaveFlags.SaveCustomColumnHeaders);
          ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        }
        Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What I would suggest is to create a proxy FpSpread and copy the contents of your Orignal data into proxy object.
2. create new column in Proxy FPSpread and then let the Farpoint.SaveExcel() take care of export.

   ```
       FpSpread fpproxy = new FpSpread();
       fpproxy = OriginalFPspread;

       fpproxy .ActiveSheetView.AddColumns(0, 2);// add new column

       fpproxy .Cells[0, 1].Column.Label = "your data";
       fpproxy .Cells[0, 1].Value = "your value";
   ```

After adding this data, call your SaveExcel() on fpproxy